# limit nested for loop output

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-sdk

i am running the below code to get a list of security groups and i get the expected behaviour but i am trying to see if there is a way to make this code so that the output only spits out inbound rule once with the source...so for security group called "wordpress-app-SG" output would look something like below

```
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(22-22)]  source: [67.184.225.222/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(80-80)]  source: [24.12.30.198/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: [IPPermissions:udp(53-53)]  source: [24.12.30.198/32]
```

Here is what i am working with so far...

```
SecurityGroup:default sg-e1304484 inbound: [IPPermissions:-1(None-None), IPPermissions:tcp(5500-5500)]  source: [67.184.225.222/32]
SecurityGroup:default sg-e1304484 inbound: [IPPermissions:-1(None-None), IPPermissions:tcp(5500-5500)]  source: [67.184.225.222/32]
SecurityGroup:Pub_HDP_SG sg-e632d982 inbound: [IPPermissions:-1(None-None)]  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
SecurityGroup:RDP Rule - open everyone  sg-42d58d27 inbound: [IPPermissions:-1(None-None)]  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
SecurityGroup:us-east-open-all sg-97ffa7f2 inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(22-22), IPPermissions:tcp(53-53)]  source: [10.0.1.2/32]
SecurityGroup:us-east-open-all sg-97ffa7f2 inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(22-22), IPPermissions:tcp(53-53)]  source: [10.0.1.2/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(22-22), IPPermissions:tcp(80-80), IPPermissions:udp(53-53)]  source: [67.184.225.222/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(22-22), IPPermissions:tcp(80-80), IPPermissions:udp(53-53)]  source: [24.12.30.198/32]
SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG sg-99c4befc inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(22-22), IPPermissions:tcp(80-80), IPPermissions:udp(53-53)]  source: [24.12.30.198/32]
SecurityGroup:default sg-c65a20a3 inbound: [IPPermissions:-1(None-None), IPPermissions:-1(None-None)]  source: [sg-c65a20a3-995635159130]
SecurityGroup:default sg-c65a20a3 inbound: [IPPermissions:-1(None-None), IPPermissions:-1(None-None)]  source: [sg-99c4befc-995635159130]
SecurityGroup:AWS-AMI-SG sg-35568d51 inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(22-22)]  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
SecurityGroup:launch-wizard-2 sg-932255f6 inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(22-22), IPPermissions:tcp(443-443)]  source: [10.0.1.2/32]
SecurityGroup:launch-wizard-2 sg-932255f6 inbound: [IPPermissions:tcp(22-22), IPPermissions:tcp(443-443)]  source: [0.0.0.0/0]
>>>
```

Comment: Can you phrase your question more clearly please?  Is there a specific security group id that you want?

Comment: As an aside, this code is very inefficient and can easily break. You should call get_all_security_groups() once, and once only. Store the results in a variable and then use that variable for subsequent len() or other operations.

Comment: @jarmod, thank you for the pointers.  I am pretty new to programming so i am just trying to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import boto.ec2

sgs = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1').get_all_security_groups()

for sg in sgs:
    for rule in sg.rules:
        print sg, sg.id, "inbound:", rule, " source:", rule.grants
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure not the best way to do this, but here is what i came up with...which almost does the same thing i am looking for

```
for i in range(ln):
    sg = ec2.get_all_security_groups()[i]
    ru_ln = len(ec2.get_all_security_groups()[i].rules)
    print "\n"
    print "######################", sg, sg.id, "######################"
    print "\n"
    for g in range(ru_ln):
        so = ec2.get_all_security_groups()[i].rules[g].grants
        sg2 = ec2.get_all_security_groups()[i].rules[g]
        print "inbound:", sg2, "source:", so
```